# Not able connect to Hazelcast instance deployed on Openshift from External client

Tags: docker, openshift, hazelcast

Deployed Hazelcast image on Openshift  and I have created a route but still not able to connect to it from external Java client. I came to know that routes only work for HTTP or HTTPS services , so am I missing anything here or what do I have to do to expose that Hazelcast instance to outer world ?

And the Docker image for Hazelcast is created and it runs Hazelcast.jar inside the image , does this concern the problem I'm facing ?

I tried exposing the service by running the command
oc expose dc hazelcast --type=LoadBalancer --name=hazelcast-ingress

and external IP with different port number was generated and I tried that as well still getting "exception com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException" and not able to connect to it.

Thanks in advance, any guidance would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you got into the running pod and seen if you can ``curl`` the local port for the application to see if it is responding?

Comment: the pod is running but not able to curl the port

Comment: To clarify, are you running ``curl`` from inside of the pod. That is, did you ``oc rsh`` into the pod and run it there. I am not talking about using ``curl`` against the exposed URL for the route. So you would be running ``curl localhost:8080`` and ``curl $HOSTNAME:8080`` in the pod. Change port 8080 to whatever port it is listening on. If that doesn't work, then does the logs show anything interesting.

Comment: I tried "curl localhost:5701" from inside the POD terminal  and I got this as response
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: At least it says it accepted the connection. It was a silly thing to ask though, as I somehow managed to not infer you were saying wasn't a HTTP service.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-openshift#hazelcast-client), "...If the client application is outside the OpenShift project, then the cluster needs to be exposed by the service with externalIP and the Hazelcast client needs to have the Smart Routing feature disabled".